# How to find top 3 employee in every department having higest salary in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hiveql

```
name, salary, department
joe, 95000, Manager
walter, 26500, HR
Adam, 36520,Developer
Sam, 38910, Developer
Romie, 68457,Manager
oliver, 69545, Developer
Mahesh, 89542, Developer
Ricky, 96845,HR
Sara, 84756,Manager
Anand, 36597, HR
Kevin, 98457, HR
Ram, 63547, Manager
```

output should be `

```
Developer, Mahesh, 89542
Developer, oliver, 69545
Developer, Sam, 38910
HR, Kevin, 98457
HR, Ricky, 96845
HR, Anand, 36597
Manager, joe, 95000
Manager, Sara, 84756
Manager, Romie, 68457

`
```

I want all the record should be printed like the given output, and this should run in hive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select dept, name, salary from (
    select name, salary, dept, row_number() over(partition by dept order by salary desc) as rn 
    from employee_sal
    ) emp 
where emp.rn<4;
```

Result will be look like below:

`name  salary  dept
Mahesh 89542 Developer
oliver 69545 Developer
Sam 38910 Developer
Kevin 98457 HR
Ricky 96845 HR
Anand 36597 HR
joe 95000 Manager
Sara 84756 Manager
Romie 68457 Manager`

Comment: Thank You @Akash Jain. This query is working as expected.